# powershell with JSON and embedded objects

Tags: json, powershell

I have following *ConvertFrom-Json* output from JSON file:

```
Id                 : 1
ItemName           : TestFile
SharingInformation : {@{RecipientEmail=complianceadmin@dev.onmicrosoft.com; ResharePermission=Read}, @{RecipientEmail=test@dev.onmicrosoft.com; ResharePermission=Read}}
```

I would like to save this data to .csv file in following manner as columns:

```
Id                 : 1
ItemName           : TestFile
RecipientEmail     : test@dev.domain.com; test2@dev.domain.com
ResharePermission  : Read; Write
```

as columns.. Here you can find part of my actual PS code (which do not work properly when there is more than one embedded values):

```
$JSONFile = $ExctratedFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$psObjectForCsv = $JSONFile | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "id"=$_.Id
        "ItemName"=$_.ItemName
        "RecipientEmail"=$_.SharingInformation.RecipientEmail
        "ResharePermission"=$_.SharingInformation.ResharePermission

    }
}
$psObjectForCsv | Export-Csv -path $fileName -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
```

do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!
Regards

Comment: Something like `"RecipientEmail"=$_.SharingInformation.RecipientEmail -join '; '` could work.

Comment: What is $activities ? And u will need a For-Each yes, but not like that. Second problem, u did u ConvertFrom-Json, and u still get some "@{}". Is that a String ?

Comment: @zett42 yeap, that's working fine.. thank you!! :)) I have another issue.. what if I would like to marge attribute RecipientEmail and ResharePermission together? In order to achive one attribute i.e. Users:  (read) test@dev.domain.com ; (write) test2@dev.domain.com and so on... regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join multiple values with a delimiter:

```
$psObjectForCsv = $data | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id = $_.Id
        ItemName = $_.ItemName
        RecipientEmail = $_.SharingInformation.RecipientEmail -join ";"
        ResharePermission = $_.SharingInformation.ResharePermission -join ";"
    }
}
```

Comment: yeap, that's working fine.. thank you!! :)) I have another issue.. what if I would like to marge attribute RecipientEmail and ResharePermission together? In order to achive one attribute i.e. Users:  (read) test@dev.domain.com ; (write) test2@dev.domain.com and so on... regards!

Comment: @anders1990 That's basically a different question altogether. Asking followup questions in the comments does not work very well. You can either ask that separately (open a new thread) or try yourself. Hint: Use a `for` loop.